# Rolle's theorem for a proof

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the continuous functions $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(x) = 1 + e^x \cos(x)$ and $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, g(x) = 1 + e^x \sin(x)$. Using Rolle's Theorem, prove that between any two roots of $f$ there exists at least one root of $g$.

A root of $f$ is a point $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x) = 0$

So how would you go about answering this one?

Can anyone provide a brief proof?

I have no idea and want to know before I tute tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider $F(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$, and note that $F'(x)=-e^{-x}g(x)$.